# Ejecutar sentencia AND dependiento de un valor de una variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, condiciones

En un procedimiento almacenado quiero agregar una sentencia AND a la consulta dependiendo del valor de una variable.

```
DECLARE @name as varchar(50)
SET @name = ''
SELECT * FROM Tabla T
WHERE T.campo = 'valor'
```

Aquí quisiera agregarle una sentencia AND a la consulta dependiendo del valor de @name. Si no está vacía, agregar la sentencia

```
AND T.Name like '%'+ @name + '%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Asumo que por *vacía*, realmente quieres decir una cadena vacía, y no `NULL`.  En ese caso, para evitar una solución que envuelva SQL dinámico, simplemente puedes agregar una condición en el SQL para cuando `@name` esté vacío:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla T
WHERE T.campo = 'valor'
  AND (LEN(@name) = 0 OR T.Name like '%'+ @name + '%')
```

Pero toma en cuenta que si `T.Name` no permite valores `NULL`, entonces ni siquiera es necesario agregar la condición adicional. Simplemente agregar la condición como la tienes:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla T
WHERE T.campo = 'valor'
  AND T.Name like '%'+ @name + '%'
```

... debería devolverte los resultados correctos, aun cuando `@name` esté vacío, porque `T.Name like '%%'` evaluará a *cierto* para cualquier valor de `T.Name` (que no sea `NULL`).

Comment: Puede que la consulta siga dando los mismos resultados ¿pero valdrá la pena que el motor de BD evalúe en cada registro algo que siempre dará `true`?